# Xcode: Missing Info.plist key for NSCameraUsageDescription

Tags: ios, xcode, gpuimage

After adding `GPUImage` to my `Xcode` project, my app is getting denied for Missing an `Info.plist` key for `NSCameraUsageDescription`.

> Missing `Info.plist` key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's `Info.plist` must contain an
>   `NSCameraUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

I have added the key and description to my plist in several different ways and over 10 builds have all gotten the same denial error.

Here is my `info.plist` with the Camera Usage key at the bottom.

[image: Snap of my info.plist]

Any ideas on why I still get denied when I clearly have this defined in my plist?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465687/ it is because your value is too short and/or vague.

Comment: Did you eventually solve this? I am stuck with the same problem - for a macOS app though.

Answer (score 21):

Ok it is an old one but i'd share my experience... nothing was working for me.
What i add to to was :

- using Xcode to edit the plist.info. **NOT** in an external editor !!!!
- **DO NOT** edit the text **CREATE** a new key using the + sign.
- it will ask you to replace the previous (unless the previous one has been entered wrong... my case i think)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 19):

You need to put **a particular and proper description** to use Camera in your application. One my application is denied due to improper description. So try with a proper description, maybe it will help you.

```
<key>Privacy - Camera Usage Description</key>
<string>APPNAME requires access to your phone’s camera.</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I made my description more specific and it is still denied..

Comment: Are you using Gallery as well?

Comment: I'm not even using camera, but I need GPUImage for some other internal image processing things and I think GPUImage has frameworks that may require camera.  I only get the Camera usage error in the denial email though.

Comment: Yes sir. Maybe theres a way to remove the parts that require camera capability so I can just skip this problem completely?

Comment: In case someone doesn't know  the ```<string>```  will be shown to your users while asking for permission, so you should be clear now what description should go there.

Comment: The key is xcode key. If you are editing the plist file manually, use `<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>`

Answer (score 14):

Try the both Camera and Library permission in Plist.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access camera</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Library</string>
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an older post, but for me, it took an hour to discover that I was not editing the correct Info.plist file, but the one for UI Tests. Double-check which one you are editing, it can be the cause.

Comment: That answer solved *my* problem, so I appreciate it!

Comment: Bingo - it's the little things in life.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem even I add the privacy-Camera Usage Description in the info.plist. I try to clean and rebuild the project. Reopen the Xcode. Everything doesn't work until I add the privacy-Camera Usage Description in the Custom ios Target Properties. Hope it solve your problem.
[image]

Comment: This is almost the same thing that fixed it for me. So, what you need to do is go to Project -> Packaging -> Info.plist File -> Debug and then add the path to your info plist file there. 
In my case the path was empty and XCode was simply not picking up my Info.plist file

Comment: You save my day! It works now.

Answer (score 8):

You should enter the purpose of using camera as the description. If it does not give the purpose app will get rejected.

you should add something like 
**Appname requires to access camera for taking profile picture** or **Appname requires to access camera for uploading product images**

From the apple: Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW24) link.

> To protect user privacy, an iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0, and
>   that accesses the device’s camera, must statically declare the intent
>   to do so. Include the NSCameraUsageDescription key in your app’s
>   Info.plist file and provide a purpose string for this key. If your app
>   attempts to access the device’s camera without a corresponding purpose
>   string, your app exits.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I made my description more specific and it is still denied..

Comment: What was the description that you gave?

Comment: Appname requires to access your camera to capture a picture and record a video.

Comment: It doesn't specify why you need to capture the photo or video. You should add something like "Appname requires to access camera for taking profile picture" or   "Appname requires to access camera for uploading product images"

Comment: I am not sure why it gets rejected. In the case of Brad Larsons GPUImage, this post may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26533864/7456236 . Its written by Brad Larson himself.

Comment: This addresses the OP's question directly.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error as OP. I don't know why though because I wasn't using anything related to the camera in my app. So I included this as the description and worked.

"AppName does not use the camera to capture to take a profile picture or upload profile photos."

Answer (score 3):

GPUImage is for capturing image and video, i guess adding Microphone permission might solve the issue

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to access your camera to capture a picture and record a video.</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to access your microphone to record a video.</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

**try!**

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to access your camera to capture a photo add and update profile picture.</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to access your photo library to select a photo add and update profile picture</string>
```

**NSCameraUsageDescription:** key for `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`
**NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription:** key for `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`

Comment: This doesn't explain how or why the user should use this. Although more experienced developers might understand the raw format of a plist, the asker might not. Please add an explanation to support your response

Answer (score 1):

For app store submission, The Usage description should briefly explain why we really needs that feature.

Description:

> Camera Use

is too short and doesn't explains why we actually need camera.

It should be something like:

> App Needs to use camera to take Profile picture

Comment: Thanks for the response, I made my description more specific and it is still denied..

Answer (score 1):

If you write 
Privacy - Camera Usage Description,

change to 
NSCameraUsageDescription

Answer (score 0):

you have to put accurate condition in front of any policy, "camera use" is wrong 
 here, and for this specific problem you have to put "AVCaptureDeviceInput" in front of privacy. Hope it will work for you.

For more you can go to this link and check other privacy policy as well.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html

let me know about the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things:

- Delete deriveddata
- Make sure you are not editing the ones in test folders.
- Increase development ios version to 11.0